# Groovy:Apparent variable 'classVar' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class

Tags: javascript, java, groovy

Getting subject line error while executing simple groovy program

I am new to groovy and java coding, i am getting the subject line error, which I do not think there is a problem with syntax or code

```
package test.demo

class classExample {

    static void main(args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        classExample classVar = new classExample()
        int result
        result = classVar.sub(5,2)
        println "result is: "+result
    }


    def sub(int var1, int var2){
        return (var1-var2)
    }
}
```

The function call to sub should be successful without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 major problems with your "class".

1. name your class by Java names conventions, i.e. starting with capital letter
2. define arguments or varargs for the `sub()` method.

The whole thing should look like:

```
package test.demo

class ClassExample {

    static void main(args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClassExample classVar = new ClassExample()
        int result
        result = classVar.sub(5,2)
        println "result is: "+result
    }


    def sub(var1,var2){
        return (var1-var2)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second option you have suggest is a mistake while copying, i edited it in my code later. Agree completely first option you have suggested caused the problem and I have corrected it, thank you.